# How to get the user machine's login name?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm developing a system in ASP.NET which needs user authentication. The authentication system should look up to the login name in the user machine instead of typing the username in the textbox. Then, if it's registred in the database, it should log in automatically.

How do I get, by code, the user machine's login name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

This is found in the `HttpContext.User` Property.

Comment: @RodrigoAlves Have you set your Authentication in your web.config to Windows?

Comment: No. I'm really lost. How do I do this? Do you have an article about it?

Comment: I got it! thx... but I with this property i got "Rodrigo-PC\Rodrigo", which stands for the machine name and the login name. What if I want only the login name? I mean I need to compare only "Rodrigo" to the database since every machine has a different name

Comment: As you mentioned, you will get a fully qualified name, `DOMAIN\USER`.  You could simply chop off the domain by doing something like `User.Identity.Name.Split('\')[1]`

Comment: +1 @RodrigoAlves It should be noted `Domain1\Rodrigo` is different from `Domain2\Rodgrigo`. They are 2 distinct users and will be handled that way by Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try a couple of these options:

```
Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_USER")
Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
```

Comment: This will not give the client's username.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is an intranet application and you're using Windows Authentication, there is no way to get that information.

If you enable Windows Authentication, the user will be prompted to enter their domain credentials, after which you'll be able access their username like this:

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name;
```